# A before delete trigger in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that deletes all foreign keys before deleting the actual record.

The problem is that when I delete a record it disappears in SQL Server Management Studio, but when I refresh the page I found it again. Anyone know where the problem is?

```
 create Trigger deleteAffaire on AFFAIRE INSTEAD OF DELETE As 
 begin
    Declare @deletedAffaireId int
    Declare @deletedPlanId int

    set @deletedPlanId = 0;

    select @deletedAffaireId = id_affaire from deleted;

    begin
       select @deletedPlanId = ID_ASSURENCE 
       from ASSURANCE_QUALITE 
       where ASSURANCE_QUALITE.ID_AFFAIRE = @deletedAffaireId;

       delete from ASSURANCE_CONTACT_FONCTION 
       where ASSURANCE_CONTACT_FONCTION.ID_ASSURANCE = @deletedPlanId;

       delete from JALON 
       where JALON.ID_JALON in (select ID_JALON from ASSURANCE_JALON_TYPE 
                                where ASSURANCE_JALON_TYPE.ID_ASSURENCE = @deletedPlanId);

       delete from ASSURANCE_JALON_TYPE 
       where ASSURANCE_JALON_TYPE.ID_ASSURENCE = @deletedPlanId;

       delete from DOCUMENT 
       where DOCUMENT.ID_DOCUMENT in (select ID_DOCUMENT from ASSURENCE_DOCUMENT_TYPE 
                                      where ASSURENCE_DOCUMENT_TYPE.ID_ASSURENCE = @deletedPlanId);

       delete from ASSURENCE_DOCUMENT_TYPE 
       where ASSURENCE_DOCUMENT_TYPE.ID_ASSURENCE = @deletedPlanId;

       delete from ASSURANCE_QUALITE 
       where ASSURANCE_QUALITE.ID_ASSURENCE = @deletedPlanId;
    end
 end
```

Comment: Your first problem is that your trigger assumes that `deleted` only contains 1 row. That's a very broken assumption.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger on the table `AFFAIRE` yet in the trigger body you fail to actually delete anything from `AFFAIRE`.

An `INSTEAD OF` trigger is not a 'before' trigger. Is, as the name suggests, an **instead of** trigger. If you fail to actually delete the rows ion the trigger then... they're not deleted.

Are you sure you cannot achieve what you want using more conventional ways, like cascading delete on foreign keys?

Comment: I know that I can use cascading delete but when  I will use cascading delete it will delete all recorders from all tables that refers to the Affaire table. thats why I am trying to use a before trigger. I try for but it does'nt work so instead of i seem at first that it work but when I refresh the page I found the records

Comment: @slatniawadii, cascading was created for deleting all values wich refer to another value that is being deleted. When working with FK, when deleting a value, the database will trip because a FK must have a relation, by deleting a value, the subvalues need to be deleted as well, otherwise you will get a database filled with wrong items.

Comment: yes I know what you mean I but I need it with trigger not with default cascad

Comment: You can put cascading delete on some references and not others, so if you had it on the relationship between `ASSURANCE_QUALITE.ID_AFFAIR` and `AFFAIR.ID_ASSURENCE` for example, you could remove that part of the trigger above, and so on, other relationships will not cascade but just throw the normal error. So yes, this trigger is (after the fix Remus suggests here) just a poor substitute for cascade delete with nothing added except the possibility of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the record that you were trying to delete in the trigger at the end. Since its a instead of trigger, it won't delete actually unless you explicitly do it in the trigger.